# How do I validate non-required fields in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm building an API in CodeIgniter, and I'm having trouble with the validation for an UPDATE method. My table has 3 columns (plus id):

- first_name
- last_name
- city

I'd like the client to be able to update any of the 3 columns, and apply validation rules (such as min_length[1]) to each one the client wants to update.

The issue is that if the client POSTs this:

`first_name=Foo&last_name=`

It skips validating `last_name` since CodeIgniter sees it as "empty" and it's not "required" by my validation. But then when active record attempts to `UPDATE` the record in MySQL, it sets `last_name` to `""` (empty).

I don't want the fields to be *required*, but if they are set, they should have a minimum length.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pass the current values from database to the view file and insert them as value in html inputs as default. The validation class has a bug in current version, recently I sent a PR to CI Repository on github and fix that in v3.0. Here is the SO issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771980/how-to-validate-array-value-in-codeigniter/17773575

Comment: Pleas post the code of updating the db

Comment: @HashemQolami there is no view - this is an API that outputs JSON. On validation error, it will simply respond with the errors.

Comment: @dianuj It's just ActiveRecord's `$this->db->where('id', $id)->update('table', $this->post());` nothing fancy

Comment: @TobiasFünke So simply check whether the variable is empty or not before updating the row.

Comment: In case anyone else comes upon this question, it is still unanswered. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this i am giving you an example for your scenario the fields which are not mandatory and for first time they has values that are stored in db and for second time user just sent blank any of the mandatory fields just unset that index in your to store in db so the previous value will remain in DB

```
$first_name=$this->input->post("first_name");
$last_name=$this->input->post("last_name");
$city=$this->input->post("city");
$data = array(
               'first_name' => $first_name,
               'last_name' => $last_name,
               'city' => $city
            );

if(empty($last_name)){
unset($data['last_name'])
}
if(empty($city)){
unset($data['city'])
}
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Actually `empty()` breaks `'0'`. use `===''` operator instead.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems a bit silly to do all these manual overrides because of a quirk in the built-in validation. There has to be a way to do it properly...