# how to show validation error message for array element?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="ndetails" value="<?php echo $ndetails; ?>"/>
  <?php
  for ($i=1; $i<=$ndetails; $i++)
  {
  ?>
    <textarea name="mydetails[]"></textarea>
    <?php echo form_error('mydetails[]'); ?>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</form>
```

and in the controller, I use a form validation like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$this->input->post('ndetails'); $i++)
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('mydetails[]', 'Day '.$i, 'trim|required');
}
```

the problem is when there's more than 1 textarea, the `form_error('mydetails[]')` only show the last error message. how can I show the errors individually after each textarea?

Comment: looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802145/689579, it looks like you could set the array key -> `<textarea name="mydetails[<?php echo $i ?>]">...`, `<?php echo form_error('mydetails['.$i.']'); ?>`, `$this->form_validation->set_rules('mydetails['.$i.']', 'Day '.$i, 'trim|required');`

Answer (score 0):

Use this : Code not tested

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="ndetails" value="<?php echo $ndetails; ?>"/>
  <?php
  for ($i=1; $i<=$ndetails; $i++)
  {
   $j=$i-1;
    echo "<textarea name='mydetails[".$j."]'></textarea>";
    echo form_error('mydetails['.$j.']'); 
  }
  ?>
</form>
```