# How to validate value of array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, validation

I am working on insert data using `codeigniter`.
Here is the post data array which i get.

**Problem**: I am sending the `app_soft_ids`, `lang_ids`, `working_days` form my HTML form and so i get that in post as shown in post array here. But `codeigniter` didn't validate this three values.

How do i validate this three value? `codeigniter` Shows this Error after validation. I didn't get that how is it possible that i am sending data properly but CI validation still didn't get it.

> The Application IDs field is required.
>
> The Langusge IDs field is required.
>
> The Working Days field is required.

Here is my post array.

```
Array
(
    [app_soft_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66
            [1] => 68
        )

    [lang_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )
    [working_days] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [shift] => Y    
    [status] => O
    [expiry_date] => 10/07/2017
)
```

This is my validation code:

```
$config = array(
    'app_validation' => array(
        array(
                'field' => 'app_soft_ids',
                'label' => 'Application IDs',
                'rules' => 'required|numeric'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'lang_ids',
                'label' => 'Langusge IDs',
                'rules' => 'required|numeric'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'working_days',
                'label' => 'Working Days',
                'rules' => 'required|numeric'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'shift',
                'label' => 'Shift',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[1]|'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: you are validating with numeric rules on array data type. check this link https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/2547

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771980/how-to-validate-array-value-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kumar_v comment I have get the way to validate the array is just add the `[]` init.

```
$config = array(
    'app_validation' => array(
        array(
                'field' => 'app_soft_ids[]',
                'label' => 'Application IDs',
                'rules' => 'required|numeric'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'lang_ids[]',
                'label' => 'Langusge IDs',
                'rules' => 'required|numeric'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'working_days[]',
                'label' => 'Working Days',
                'rules' => 'required|numeric'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'shift',
                'label' => 'Shift',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[1]|'
        )
    )
);
```