# Array to string conversion error when getting set_value in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a form with validation. I want to keep the values of the form when the validation failed using `set_value` in the textboxes. These textboxes are using array for the name.

```
<input type="text" name="speed[]" value="<?php echo set_value('speed[]') ?>" />
```

I believe that this is exactly what is pointed out by the documentation [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array). But when the form submitted, I get "Array to string conversion" error. I wonder how to implement this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an index between the square brackets in `set_value`.

Assuming you're using a loop to print the textboxes, you can do the following:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="speed[]" value="<?php echo set_value('speed['.$i.']') ?>" />
<?php endfor; ?>
```

---

And to validate/display errors for each field separately, set the validation rules in a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('speed['.$i.']', 'Speed', 'required');
}
```

Then you can use the index in `form_error`:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="speed[]" value="<?php echo set_value('speed['.$i.']') ?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('speed['.$i.']'); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Credits to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802145/3960296

Comment: Ah you're right! It works! Now I wonder how to populate the error message? I tried `<?php echo form_error('speed['. $i .']') ?>` but it was not showing.